# What does the double asterisk mean in proguard rules?

Tags: proguard

What does this rule mean in proguard for example:

```
-keep class myjava.** {*;}
```

I understand {*;} part would mean all members and methods in the class. But what does the 2 asterisk mean in the package name?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From [the manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/refcard):

```
Types in classname, annotationtype, returntype, and argumenttype can contain
wildcards: '?' for a single character, '*' for any number of characters (but
not the package separator), '**' for any number of (any) characters, '%' for
any primitive type, '***' for any type, and '...' for any number of arguments.
```

Comment: I still dont get it. So whats the different between -keep @@annotation.Singleton public class * and -keep @@annotation.Singleton public class **

Comment: @BasilMusa if I understand correctly, a single asterix doesn't include the package separater, so, for example: com.google.* would keep com.google.test or com.google.anothertest but *not* com.google.test.one. A double asterisk would keep all potential subpackages ad infinitum

Comment: so without {*;} you don't keep members and methods, so what would you be keeping exactly?

Comment: For me using the double asterisk requires inserting `#noinspection ShrinkerUnresolvedReference` above the line, guess it depends on your environment setup