# Meaning of { *; } in ProGuard

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

Consider this proguard statement :

```
-keep public class * extends android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior { *; }
```

In this statement what does the addition of { *; } mean?

Does it preserve all methods? All fields? Or just the entire class?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is used as a wildcard in ProGuard to indicate `all members and methods in the class`.

Source: [ProGuard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#manual/refcard.html), [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727162/what-does-the-double-asterisk-mean-in-proguard-rules)

Comment: so is it the same as keepclassmembers or keepclasswithmembers?