# Cause of "Failed to register native method" error?

Tags: android, renderscript

I am working on two projects; one is smaller (I will call this `ProjectA`), while the other is quite large (`ProjectB`). Both projects make use of the same library, the [Photo Editor SDK by IMG.LY](https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/). For both projects I followed the simple integration steps on in the [documentation for the library](https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/documentation/android/integration).

`ProjectA` uses a custom `Activity` to display and pick the images, while `ProjectB` just uses a simple `ACTION_PICK` intent to choose an image. Both projects have a similar method to start the `PhotoEditorActivity` after an image is chosen; except the method in `ProjectA` accepts a `File` parameter, while the other accepts a `Uri`:

```
private void dispatchEditorIntent(File file /* Uri uri */) {
    new PhotoEditorIntent(getActivity())
            .setExportDir(PhotoEditorIntent.Directory.PICTURES, getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setExportPrefix(Constants.PREFIX_EDITOR)
            .setSourceImagePath(file.getAbsolutePath()) // uri.getPath() for ProjectB
            .destroySourceAfterSave(false)
            .startActivityForResult(REQUEST_EDITOR);
}
```

If I choose the same image in either project, the `file.getAbsolutePath()` or `uri.getPath()` method will return the same `String`; for example:

> /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20160929_145318_395198580.jpeg

`ProjectA` works fine, yet in `ProjectB` when `dispatchEditorIntent` is called, I am met with a gigantic error message. For brevity I included only the first 10 lines of each the error and alert logs:

```
09-29 14:53:26.585 4272-4272/com.example.projectb E/art: Failed to register native method android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.nDeviceDestroy(J)V in /data/app/com.example.projectb-1/base.apk
09-29 14:53:26.587 4272-4272/com.example.projectb E/art: ----- class 'Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript;' cl=0x32c34dc0 -----
09-29 14:53:26.587 4272-4272/com.example.projectb E/art:   objectSize=792 (432 from super)
09-29 14:53:26.587 4272-4272/com.example.projectb E/art:   access=0x8008.0001
09-29 14:53:26.587 4272-4272/com.example.projectb E/art:   super='java.lang.Class<java.lang.Object>' (cl=0x0)
09-29 14:53:26.587 4272-4272/com.example.projectb E/art:   vtable (81 entries, 11 in super):
09-29 14:53:26.587 4272-4272/com.example.projectb E/art:      0: void android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.finalize()
09-29 14:53:26.587 4272-4272/com.example.projectb E/art:      1: android.content.Context android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.getApplicationContext()
09-29 14:53:26.587 4272-4272/com.example.projectb E/art:      2: boolean android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.isAlive()
09-29 14:53:26.587 4272-4272/com.example.projectb E/art:      3: boolean android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.isUseNative()

...

09-29 14:53:26.617 4272-4272/com.example.projectb A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewGlobalRef called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static or non-static method "Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript;.nDeviceDestroy(J)V"
09-29 14:53:26.617 4272-4272/com.example.projectb A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String) (Runtime.java:-2)
09-29 14:53:26.617 4272-4272/com.example.projectb A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.doLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Runtime.java:1060)
09-29 14:53:26.617 4272-4272/com.example.projectb A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at void java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String) (Runtime.java:975)
09-29 14:53:26.617 4272-4272/com.example.projectb A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at void java.lang.System.loadLibrary(java.lang.String) (System.java:1530)
09-29 14:53:26.617 4272-4272/com.example.projectb A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.internalCreate(android.content.Context, int, android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript$ContextType, int) (RenderScript.java:1385)
09-29 14:53:26.617 4272-4272/com.example.projectb A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.create(android.content.Context, int, android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript$ContextType, int) (RenderScript.java:1576)
09-29 14:53:26.617 4272-4272/com.example.projectb A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.create(android.content.Context, android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript$ContextType, int) (RenderScript.java:1526)
09-29 14:53:26.617 4272-4272/com.example.projectb A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.create(android.content.Context, android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript$ContextType) (RenderScript.java:1502)
09-29 14:53:26.617 4272-4272/com.example.projectb A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.create(android.content.Context) (RenderScript.java:1489)

...
```

After some research I came across questions about similar errors, but none of the answers were applicable. I am fairly certain this is not an issue with the library considering I have it working in one project, but I cannot figure out what causes this error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what may be causing this?

Comment: I had a similar "Failed to register native method" that was being caused by my Proguard configuration. I fixed it by adding a couple of `-keep` statements that basically tell ProGuard to not throw away any classes or methods that it thinks that aren't necessary in the packages I specified. Check if you're using ProGuard and if so, make sure the config is correct.

Comment: Also, speaking of ProGuard... the default ProGuard rules that ship in the Android plugin changed in version 2.2, so check if the projects are running with the same versions of Gradle and plugins.

Comment: Yep, it was ProGuard... it always is when I least expect it. I didn't find anything that suggested it might be, and you would think RenderScript would include its own ProGuard rules. Also, my Gradle plugin for both projects is the same version, I'll keep an eye out for that in the future though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

+1 for @Mike Laren's comments

I have seen similar problems before, and the fix is to add the following lines to the proguard config:

```
-dontwarn android.support.v8.renderscript.*
-keepclassmembers class android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript {
  native *** rsn*(...);
  native *** n*(...);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue today, and since I am using Android X, I had to add the following to my `proguard-rules.pro` file.

```
# Render Script
-keep class android.support.v8.renderscript.** { *; }
-keep class androidx.renderscript.** { *; }
```

This will take care of apps that use the Android support library, as well as Android X.

Comment: This might be a bit overkill, since (as in the answer by @MiaoWang) keeping specific class members of the `RenderScript` class was enough. Keeping the same class members of the `androidx.renderscript.RenderScript` class should be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! I'll try on my next release build and edit my answer.

Comment: Why do you use `{ *; }`?

Comment: @BeniBela I think I found the suggestion on https://github.com/mmin18/RealtimeBlurView/issues/15 from a library I was facing an issue with. If you have any improvement suggestions, let me know.

Comment: I just want to know what it does and why it is needed. It is impossible to google. I thought -keep class would be enough without `{*;}` to keep all of the class, but without it, my app crashes. There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32455157/meaning-of-in-proguard), but no clear answer. Why not `{; }` or `{*; *}` or `{*; **}` or `{**; **}`...

Comment: Check Class Specifications [here](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage).