# How to solve generate apk after added pro-guard in grade fail error?

Tags: android, proguard

While I tried to enable pro-guard in my project and generate an apk, I got build failed.

The error message is

> Expecting type and name instead of just '***' before '(' in line 367
>   of file 'D:\AMS
>   mobile\PhoonEw\app\build\intermediates\proguard-rules\dev\release\aapt_rules.txt'

My build.gradle pro-guard code

```
release {
      debuggable false
      shrinkResources true
      minifyEnabled true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

And lineno 367 is error

[image]

Comment: A `***` is not valid in pro-guard I'm assuming you are trying to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17257093/8608146) and related [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727162/what-does-the-double-asterisk-mean-in-proguard-rules)

Comment: it is expecting some matching function name you want to add in prguard rules. e.g  *** d() -- for log.d

Comment: Even proguard file does not have the code, it is showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline 367 it pointing .xml file, so I come to this screen and check error. The main problem I got is I declared onClick=" "(no function name). So this coz problem in generating application release.[xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCf5n.png)